# How to setup mongo-migrate-ts with nx workspace

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx

I've created nx workspace with nest.js application. I would like to add mongo-migrate-ts support which normally was started by "ts-node migrations/index.ts up" as script in packages.json. In my nx project, when I try to add script in global package.json, it says that "ts" extension is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typescript rewrite of the original migrate mongo, much like mongo-migrate-ts, but this one is in the form of a nx plug-in. It will work a lot better for your needs if you are using nx. It is called nx-mongo-migrate. Give it a shot!

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will mark your answer as accepted, but after a year it's not longer relevant for me - I have wrote my own migration functionality code and never looked back ;)